# Twitter bootstrap fluid row background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add a unified background to all of the div-s with span indexed from 2-11.
The HTML is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div id="main_div">    <!--Background starts here !!! -->
    <div class="span2" id="timetable">Timetable</div>
    <div class="span6" id="game_window">Game window</div>
            <div class="span2" id="stuff">Stuff</div>
        </div>                <!--Background ends here !!! -->
        <div class="span1"></div>
    </div><!--row-fluid-->
</div><!--container-fluid-->
```

The supposed background is marked with comments also. The background should be for div#main_div. At the moment this way if I add a background color to #main_div it will set it as the bgcolor of all of the span elements.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What browser support do you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your html to wrap the inner span elements within a row.

Try something like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span10">
           <div class="row-fluid" id="main_div">    <!--Background start!!! -->
              <div class="span2" id="timetable">Timetable</div>
              <div class="span6" id="game_window">Game window</div>
              <div class="span2" id="stuff">Stuff</div>
           </div>                <!--Background end!!! -->
        </div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
    </div><!--row-fluid-->
</div><!--container-fluid-->
```

now, if you add the background it will be applied to the required elements only.

eg,

```
#main_div {
   background:orange;
}
```

see a full fiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/YTJub/

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Apply an unified one by exluding bad ones as follow:

```
#main_div :not(.span1, .span12) {background-color:#f00 }
```

Note that these CSS3 selectors don't work on all browsers, particularly older versions of Internet Explorer will happily ignore them.

Comment: `span12` is the entire width of the page, not the last span element.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not open the .CSS file and change the span 2 - 11 classes to have the background orange?

I believe its about halfway down in boostrap.css as follows:

```
.span12 {
width: 940px;
}
```

just add:

```
 .span12 {
width: 940px;
background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: Doing something like this would have a major impact.  Would this not apply to all instances of the `span` classes?

Comment: Yes it would. If that's not what your after, then I would not recommend this method.